# Mobile Navbar SSR

Tags: googlebot, technical-seo, react-js, server-side-scripting, next.js

Currently, we serve our site using SSR. On some parts of the site, we render components based on the screen size (mobile navbar for example).
The SSR is serving the desktop version.

So, Googlebot always gets the desktop version and dont 'see' the mobile version.
Since I cannot make the navbar menu responsive (it is a completely different design) How should I serve this navbar?

Will it be okay to serve both and hide the mobile version? or should I serve just one of them and load the other one on the client?
It's extremely important for us that Googlebot will go over our navbar menu and I am not sure how should I do that.
Thanks

Comment: Can you make a link to the mobile site in the navbar menu?

Comment: It's under the same site..